# opencv solver c++ function optimization

Tags: c++, opencv, optimization, makefile

i am new in opencv optimization and i make simple example of using conjugate gradient solver like this:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

class Rosenbrock: public MinProblemSolver::Function {
    int getDims() const {
        return 2;
    };
    double calc(const double* x) const {
        return 100*(x[1] - x[0]*x[0])*(x[1]-x[0]*x[0]) + (1 - x[0])*(1-x[0]);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Ptr<ConjGradSolver> solver = makePtr<ConjGradSolver>();
    solver->setFunction(Rosenbrock);
    Mat x = (Mat_<double>(2, 1) << 0.0, 0.0);
    double fval = solver->minimize(x);
    std::cout << fval << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

with this makefile

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -g -Wall
SRCS = HelloWorld.cpp
PROG = HelloWorld

OPENCV = `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`
LIBS = $(OPENCV)

$(PROG):$(SRCS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(PROG) $(SRCS) $(LIBS)
```

but when i am trying to compile, it will appears errors:

```
g++ -g -Wall -o HelloWorld HelloWorld.cpp `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`
HelloWorld.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
HelloWorld.cpp:17:35: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
     solver->setFunction(Rosenbrock);
                                   ^
HelloWorld.cpp:19:12: warning: unused variable ‘fval’ [-Wunused-variable]
     double fval = solver->minimize(x);
            ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:1037:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/base.hpp:58,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:54,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:52,
                 from HelloWorld.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/ptr.inl.hpp: In instantiation of     ‘cv::Ptr<T> cv::makePtr() [with T = cv::ConjGradSolver]’:
HelloWorld.cpp:16:58:   required from here
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/ptr.inl.hpp:301:26: error: invalid new-    expression of abstract class type ‘cv::ConjGradSolver’
     return Ptr<T>(new T());
                          ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:3225:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:52,
                 from HelloWorld.cpp:1:
```

I will be gratefull for any advice,
sincerely,
Paul.

Comment: Haven't looked at the documentation for `setFunction`, but five bucks says you want an instance of `Rosenbrock`, not the class, at `solver->setFunction(Rosenbrock);`.

Comment: looks like adding lin Rosenbrock* pokus = new Rosenbrock(); work man, thanks ;-)
but there is still one error:
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/ptr.inl.hpp:301:26: error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type ‘cv::ConjGradSolver’
     return Ptr<T>(new T());
any idea? maybe i wrote line wrong but i dont think so.

Comment: No clue on the second one, I'm afraid. Not familiar enough with opencv. See if you can get by with `Rosenbrock pokus; solver->setFunction(&pokus);`. Less manual memory management dropped in your lap.

Comment: Still some errors, anyway thanks for advices man. ;)

Comment: I got it man: 
I added these lines
    Ptr<ConjGradSolver::Function> pokus(new   Rosenbrock());
    Ptr<ConjGradSolver> solver = ConjGradSolver::create();
    solver->setFunction(pokus);

Time to find solution for about +- 100k parameters. :D And again thanks for help. I apprechiate it.

Comment: Might be worth writing up a formal answer to help other folks who need to recreate what you've figured out.

Answer (score 0):

Now its working. I inspired by code in this link:
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/test/test_conjugate_gradient.cpp#L107
I replaced 
    `Ptr<ConjGradSolver> solver = makePtr<ConjGradSolver>();
solver->setFunction(Rosenbrock);`

with

`Ptr<ConjGradSolver::Function> pokus(new Rosenbrock()); 
Ptr<ConjGradSolver> solver = ConjGradSolver::create(); solver->setFunction(pokus);`